# How to play tremolo on violin

Tags: notation, orchestral-strings, tremolo

I found an orchestral score in 3/4 time that instructs the first and second violins to play tremolos:

[image]

First violins should play those notes as quavers so do the second violins play semiquavers? I think this could be a typo and that 2nd violins should play quavers for the entire bar. Otherwise it doesn't make sense.

**Edit:** I'm referring to bar 82 in this [arrangement](https://www.free-scores.com/sheetmusic?p=as8Y02AiTi) of Shostakovich's Waltz No. 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dots should align in music - for example where there are two quavers, with a crotchet under the first, the next dots should be vertically in line with each other.

On that premise, this does look, as you say, like a typo, and if the violin 1's part is a full bar (which it must be in 3/4 time), then the violin 2's part should be the same three crotchets. Pity the barline has been cut off - it could be that the violin1's part matches with two quavers instead!

Comment: (@MedullaOblongata But, just to clarify, although the two sections *probably* have matching note values here, there's nothing wrong with putting a slash through the stem of a quaver, which yes, would mean semiquavers.)

Comment: @AndyBonner - playing tremolo as semiquavers reading quaver notes seems quite a slow tremolo to me.

Comment: We haven't even touched the fact that "tremolo" is maybe not the best word to use for this excerpt. When clarifying, we can talk about "measured" v "unmeasured" tremolo; when we use the word without clarification we're usually talking about the latter ("Play this pitch as fast as you can, it doesn't matter that the section won't be together"). If we could take this excerpt seriously it would be calling for "measured tremolo," i.e. using this notation as a shorthand to save writing a bunch of 8th notes and/or 16th notes.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I didn't realise that. Thought tremolo was basically 'play as quickly as you can on the same note' - a la mandolin.

Comment: Yeah, it often means you have to stop and ask which one is intended. The unmeasured one is usually indicated by putting enough slashes to equal 32nd notes—especially because most of the time you can't even be very precise about 32nds—but maybe sometimes at a slow tempo they really want true 32nds? Or maybe somebody used two slashes to mean unmeasured?

Answer (score 0):

This appears like a very clear engraving mistake on first glance, but strangely creating this mistake is not easy. It would basically require adding invisible rests between the notes (from the looks of it I think this is engraved using an older version of MuseScore). A different reason could be that Violin 1 somehow had the flags hidden, but the spacing looks awfully wide and the tremolo would not make as much sense with 8th notes, as this would then change from 16th note tremolo to 8th note tremolo, which should probably not be notated this way.

Maybe you can share with us a larger excerpt of the page or the source where you found this score?